# How to Display Version of Document Template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word, custom-field-types, document-template, version

I apologize if the title is unclear, but I couldn't think of a better way to explain the question concisely. For the record, we are running SharePoint 2013 on-premises.

Basically, I am trying to see if it is possible to grab/label the version number of the template document from which a document is created. Here's the business case:

Occasionally, there are major revisions to a template file for a critical business content type. Say the content type is Case Study, and updates to the template are saved as major versions in a special library in which the templates are stored.

So using this example, I'm looking for a way to distinguish documents that were created using **casestudy.dotx Version 1.0** from documents that were created using **casestudy.dotx Version 2.0**. Ideally, "template version" would be a metadata column that I could link (using MS Word > Insert Field > Label) in the footer of the document.

I consulted the following documentation to learn how to use Information Management Policy > Label to display the **current document's** version: http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/06/sharepoint-display-sp-version-number-in-a-word-document/. But again, I am not looking for the document's version; I am looking for the version of the template file whence the document was created.

Thank you for your time and suggestions!

**EDIT**: If you're curious what my end-game is: I want to figure out a way to retire documents that (among other conditions) were created with an older version of the casestudy.dotx template. Ultimately, I'm thinking that I can apply a retention schedule based on template version (again, among other conditions). To me, this plan seems preferable to having two content types ("Old Case Study" vs "Current Case Study" or something) to record the differences from year to year.